# Oracle Data Pump Import Error on AWS RDS ORA-31626: job does not exist

Tags: oracle19c

I am testing the Oracle data pump for data migration to AWS RDS Oracle instance 19C.

I am importing one table to Oracle instance.
I am using following command:

```
impdp test1/<Password>@aws_rds_dms1 parfile=odd-import-parameter1.txt
```

What should be the User name on the TABLES parameter? (admin was from export and not inserting in test1)?

I used similar approach for exporting the table and it worked.

Can someone please suggest what should be changed in parameters and scripts?

What commands and access/Roles should I grant to test1?

This is AWS RDS Oracle instance.

Comment: I am getting following list of errors in Import:


Import: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Jun 1 14:49:02 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
   ORA-31626: job does not exist
   ORA-31633: unable to create master table "AIS_419.SYS_IMPORT_TABLE_05"
   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
   ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1163  
   ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'
   ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1056
   ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1044

Comment: I am using following command:

impdp test1/<Password>@aws_rds_dms1 parfile=odd-import-parameter1.txt

The parameter file looks like:
   DIRECTORY=ODD_URECASE1
   DUMPFILE=urecase1.exp
   LOGFILE=urecase1-import.log
   EXCLUDE=statistics
   PARALLEL=1
   TABLES=admin.urecase
   table_exists_action=truncate

Comment: The parameter file looks like:
   DIRECTORY=ODD_URECASE1
   DUMPFILE=urecase1.exp
   LOGFILE=urecase1-import.log
   EXCLUDE=statistics
   PARALLEL=1
   TABLES=admin.urecase
   table_exists_action=truncate

Comment: Please edit your question to add that information as formatted text, rather than as comments. This doesn't really seem to be anything to do with AWS so you might want to re-tag it too. The error says that your test1 user doesn't have privileges on the USER tablespace, so you'll at least need to set that up. It sounds like you might have created the user but need to add all the privileges it needs, possibly just copying what it had on the database you exported from.